# converting from mysql to mssql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, codeigniter

I am trying to use codeigniter and MS-SQL. I have to use ci_sessions table to automatically store the sessions in the mssql server. The codeigniter have provided the ci_sessions table sql in user-guide as below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
    session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    ip_address varchar(16) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
    last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    user_data text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (session_id),
    KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
);
```

. Here, I have to create the same table in MS SQL Server. What can be corresponding sql for MS SQL SERVER and also for below captcha sql table:

```
CREATE TABLE captcha (
    captcha_id bigint(13) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    captcha_time int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    ip_address varchar(16) default '0' NOT NULL,
    word varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY `captcha_id` (`captcha_id`),
    KEY `word` (`word`)
);
```

How to create same table of above mysql query in MS SQL SERVER using sql query

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms174979.aspx

Answer (score 3):

This is an example for the first table -

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ci_sessions (
    session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    ip_address varchar(16) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
    last_activity int DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    user_data varchar(max) NOT NULL, -- use varchar(max) instead of MySQL TEXT data type
    PRIMARY KEY (session_id)
)
GO

-- Simalate MySQL 'UNSIGNED' field option
ALTER TABLE dbo.ci_sessions ADD CONSTRAINT last_activity_unsigned
  CHECK (last_activity >= 0)
GO

CREATE INDEX last_activity_idx
  ON dbo.ci_sessions (last_activity)
```

Change 'dbo' schema with your schema.

Have a look at these references - [CHECK Constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258.aspx), [Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx).